# Display a link when date equals today's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a table with various columns with one being of type `DateTime` and one being an action link. I want the link to be displayed only  if the date equals today. I can't seem to find out any information on how to do this.

The link I want to display is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })
```

If the date in the `DateTime` column does not equal today, then the link shouldn't be displayed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try just wrap your actionlink with if statement?

Comment: What time zone are you thinking of when you're talking about "today"?

Comment: It's hard to suggest something if you don't provide the code for your `DateTime` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare on the `Date` property of a `DateTime`.

```
@if (item.MyDateTimeColumn.Date == DateTime.Now.Date) {
    // Your link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time zones aside you could go

```
@if(item.DateField.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
{
    //pop stuff in here
}
```

**EDIT**

@Maarten is also correct you could just compare the date part! :D